# how to use distinct with where clause and inner join

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

i have following query i want use where clause but its show not distinct values please help me  when i use multiple columns after currentdate its doesn't shows distinct values

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ts.current_datetime, 101) AS currentdatets,ts.student_id,tc.class_name,tsi.section_name,tl.test_name FROM tblstudentmarks ts 
INNER JOIN tblclassinfo tc ON
tc.Idx = ts.class_id 
INNER JOIN tblsectioninfo tsi ON
tsi.Idx = ts.section_id 
INNER JOIN tblsubjects su ON
su.Idx = ts.subject_id 
INNER JOIN tbltestlist tl ON
tl.Idx = ts.testtype
WHERE  ts.school_id = 2 AND ts.section_id = 1 AND TS.class_id = 2 AND ts.testtype = 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but it seems like you just need to add `DISTINCT` to the select...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ts.current_datetime, 101) AS currentdate 
FROM tblstudentmarks ts 
    INNER JOIN tblclassinfo tc ON
    tc.Idx = ts.class_id 
    INNER JOIN tblsectioninfo tsi ON
    tsi.Idx = ts.section_id 
    INNER JOIN tblsubjects su ON
    su.Idx = ts.subject_id 
    INNER JOIN tbltestlist tl ON
    tl.Idx = ts.testtype
WHERE  
    ts.school_id = 2 AND ts.section_id = 1 
    AND TS.class_id = 2 AND ts.testtype = 1
```

Comment: when i use more then one column its doesn't shows distinct record datewise

Comment: so what is duplicated when you add `DISTINCT`?

Comment: its show two column same date,, check above image .. i want distinct date

Comment: That's because there are different student id, which makes the row unique

Comment: how to solve write query .. that;s show distinct date wise value , when student id are different

Comment: Just remove the student ID column

Comment: i want student id also, for get some record student table

Comment: You need to research the definition of distinct.

Comment: i need help .. in this situation i am doing, for get records with student_id

Comment: How about post what the results should look like